# csv writer, adding list items to end of row

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to parse a bunch of data to automate this report creation. I have it mostly working except the JSON data has a list of tags per item. They are nested inside each "task item".

I want the csv to look like this

`Name,Title,Description,Priority,Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4`

The below code works except since the tags in the json data are nested like

```
tags: [
{
id: 56131,
name: "NotNeeded",
color: "#a6a6a6"
},
{
id: 60598,
name: "Other",
color: "#f47fbe"
},
{
id: 60493,
name: "Test",
color: "#2f8de4"
}
```

I only want the tags, not the rest of the stuff. And I want each tag added at the end of each row. Some have three tags, some have one etc. I'm just trying to get them to write now, but with this code, they're all printing on a new line in column 1.

Further to this, I'd like to build an if statement in as well to determine which tag header it goes under...  like `if name = "Other" put under header Tag3`

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
 csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator='\n')
 csvwriter.writerow(["Name", "Title", "Description", "priority", "tags"])
 for each in jdata['todo-items']:
  csvwriter.writerow([(each["todo-list-name"]),
   (each["content"]),
   (each["description"]),
   (each["priority"])])
  for tags in each['tags']:
   csvwriter.writerow([(tags["name"])])
```

**EDIT:** This works the way I want so far (except the tags have ['Tag'] around them in the output.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
 csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator='\n')
 csvwriter.writerow(["Name", "Title", "Description", "priority", "tags"])

 for each in jdata['todo-items']:
  write_list = [(each["todo-list-name"]),
   (each["content"]),
   (each["description"]),
   (each["priority"])]
  for tags in each['tags']:
   write_list.append([(tags["name"])])
  csvwriter.writerow(write_list)
```

Comment: Do you want the tags to be separate columns, or in the same column?

Comment: separate I think would be best, so that I can just apply filters in excel later. hence I want them to match up for filter. if name is Other all the others should be in the same column. Because if one has 2 tags then it might have NotNeeded, Other  and the next only one tag, Other. without the IF statement, Other will go in the first column under NotNeeded from the previous.

Comment: @CarverStone you can now accept your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting the second for loop and adding it to the list before writing worked.
Thanks @Seanny for the help.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
 csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator='\n')
 csvwriter.writerow(["Name", "Title", "Description", "priority", "tags"])

 for each in jdata['todo-items']:
  write_list = [(each["todo-list-name"]),
   (each["content"]),
   (each["description"]),
   (each["priority"])]
  for tags in each['tags']:
   write_list.append([(tags["name"])])
  csvwriter.writerow(write_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the list before writing it out.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator='\n')
    csvwriter.writerow(["Name", "Title", "Description", "priority", "tags"])

    for each in jdata['todo-items']:
        write_list = [(each["todo-list-name"]),
                      (each["content"]),
                      (each["description"]),
                      (each["priority"])]

    for tags in each['tags']:
        write_list.append(tags["name"])

    csvwriter.writerow(write_list)
```

Comment: It works.. in terms of putting the tags in the same row at the end, but its overwriting write_list each loop and only writing the final item to the csv. Should I change the write_list = in the first loop to an append as well then?

Comment: No it didn't seem to.. and its grabbed tags from another item actually and added that to the end instead. So it's not the tags from the same item in the json data. I'll update the  question with what i mean

Comment: I think it would work if the second for loop was inside the first for loop, but i can't figure out the syntax of that inside the writer to make that work. Like the tag data should get entered like each key before it, priority, desc etc... but instead of just entering the first one it sees, it needs to loop over that nested data and add all the key values it sees before moving on to the next root item in "todo-items"

Comment: Yea.. it will take me a bit of time.. I'm only pulling a few keys out of about 100 per item. And I need to change the data since its real data and I cant post it.

Comment: in the meantime I put a second edit it in the question with what I think would work, if its possible to nest a for loop there.

Comment: Its working now. The tags are outputting with quotes and squares around them though. See my edit in the question. Thanks for you help so far. The list seems to work

Comment: Yours didn't work but it helped. Yours writes out only the last line in the loop. Nesting the second for loop works though. And apparently I can accept my own answer in two days....   *eye roll*